# Displaying xts data column name in shiny dygraph

Tags: r, xts, shiny, dygraphs

The column name is V1 in xts data and in rstudio when we change the column name

`names(dat_xts) <- "Temp"`

it gives the name of the column with column data point value (Dec, 1977: Temp:23.14) when we mouseover the dygraph plot output. However, the same doesn't happen in dygraph shiny output. In the shiny dygraph output, it gives column name as V1 (Dec, 1977: V1:23.14). How can I make shinyapp dygraph to display Temp instead of V1?

Here's the shiny [app](https://loiyumba.shinyapps.io/Global_Temp/)

And the r [code](https://gist.github.com/loiyumba/4869df51139643aaaf40d0c5a881dbbc)

Any hints gratefully received.

Comment: Your question needs a lot of work...it's not clear and certainly not reproducible.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the response! I have added the app link and the code link.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the plot legend to say "Temp" instead of "V1"? If so, you could either change the name in "india.csv" or add `dySeries("V1", label = "Temp") %>%` to your digraph call.

Comment: Thanks Paul. `dySeries("V1", label = "Temp")` did the job.